# Using jquery toggle between two options selected by checking checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

In my application I have a view where under some conditions I offer the user the ability to personally enter some basic information. However this is done dynamically so I have function in my `.js` file where if the conditions are met I made this :

```
$("#clientdata-container").append('<label>Private Client</label>...);
```

the relevant part to this question you can see in this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5tm11g9q/).

What I want to do. I want to be able to switch (toggle) between these two optins that the checkboxes offer but never to allowed both of them selected at the same time. In other words if you've seen the fiddle exmaple if a `Private Client` checkbox is checked and then the user directly check the `Company User` checkbox I want to atuomatically hide the html related to the `Private user`, uncheck the checkbox, and show the html for the `Company user`. I've been doing this using a lot of `if` checks but I feel that the `toggle()` function is just about cases like this but I have problems implementing it so I need help to make this work using toggle. Of course if it's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this : you can uncheck checkboxes excluding the clicked one using `.not()` and make empty to `clientdata-container` and fill it if checkbox is checked otherwise leave it.

```
function showHideIndividualAttributes(sender) {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(sender).prop('checked',false);
    $('#clientdata-container').empty();
    if (sender.checked) {
        $('#clientdata-container').append('<span>Private Client attributes</span>');
    } 
}

function showHideCompanyAttributes(sender) {
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(sender).prop('checked',false);
    $('#clientdata-container').empty();
    if (sender.checked) {
        $('#clientdata-container').append('<span>Company Client attributes</span>');
    } 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/5tm11g9q/5/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `append` with `html` in you code

http://jsfiddle.net/5tm11g9q/1/

Comment: Very nice and smart. Can you help me with the checkboxes too. I want to leave checked only the oen which html is shown?

Comment: @Leron If you want that kind of behavior, why not use a radio button?

Comment: @JohnroePauloCañamaque no particular reason. To be honest I'm not very sure, does this behaviour comes by default with them?

Comment: yeah, as @JohnroePauloCañamaquesaid you can just use a radio button for that

Comment: @Leron it would be easy for you to fix the problem if you would do it with radio buttons.

Comment: Thanks for help, though there was a complete answer already given. Appreciate your help and advices!